# После заполнения полей формы отправить файл на указанную почту

Tags: php

Есть простая форма с двумя полями: телефон и email. Нужно автоматически отправлять файл на почту, которую укажет пользователь в поле email.

Код обработчика

```
<?php
$to = "testgmail.com";

$headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Продажа <admin@test.com>\r\n";

$email  =  trim($_POST["email"]);
$phone  = trim($_POST["phone"]);
$message = "<b>Email:</b> $email <br> <b>Телефон:</b> $phone";
$subject = "Заявка";

mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
 mail( $email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```